# Having trouble with discord.py bot repeating itself with on_message() and modifying user messages

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to use the on_message() command to get the bot to recognize a specific kind of message, and return a modified version of that message; Here's an example:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import platform
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

client = Bot(description="Basic Bot by Habchy#1665", command_prefix="!",     pm_help = True)

@client.command()
async def ping(*args):

    await client.say(":ping_pong: Pong!")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.startswith('ABDD'):

        newMessage = message.content[:]

        newMessage.replace("D","C",1)

        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Fixed!")
        await client.send_message(message.channel, newMessage)

    await client.process_commands(message)


client.run('my auth code')
```

The first problem I'm experiencing is that my bot repeats the messages "Fixed!" and "ABDD" constantly until I shut it down.

The second problem I have is that it doesn't seem to be changing "ABDD" to "ABCD"

I'm fairly new to the whole bot making thing, and I would love some help on this problem. Thanks!

I'm using Habchy's BasicBot as a framework for my bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot tell you what is causing the repeated messages, but the reason that it doesn't change `ABDD` to `ABCD` is because `str.replace()` returns a new string instead of edits an old one.

Change `newMessage.replace("D","C",1)` to `newMessage =  newMessage.replace("D","C",1)`

Comment: This solved both problems strangely enough, I forgot that strings were immutable.

Thanks!

Comment: After thinking about it some more, the reason it was sending over and over is because you don't check to make sure you aren't replying to yourself. `if message.author.id == bot.user.id: return`